# Refreshing Component after Route Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I have a row of buttons that all links to a chart being rendered, then the button pressed, it decides which data will be shown on the chart below.

```
 <div>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route path="/chart/:topic" component={Chart} />
 </div>
```

Button element:

```
<Link to={"/chart/" + collection.name}>
      <Button key={index} data-key={index} style={this.btnStyle}>
        {this.store.capitalizeFirstLetter(collection.name)}
      </Button>
</Link>
```

This works fine when the button is pressed for the first time. However if the user tries to change the data by pressing a different button the chart component does not refresh at all, browser shows that the URL has changed however the component does not refresh at all.

I know this is because of, I've put a console.log in the chart component and it does not come up the second time a button is pressed.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   const { match: { params } } = this.props;
   this.topic = params.topic;
   console.log("chart topic", this.topic);
   this.refreshData(true);
   this.forceUpdate();
   this.store.nytTest(this.topic, this.startDate, this.endDate);
};
```

As you can see I tried to put a forceUpdate() call but that did nothing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your component is already rendered and didn't see any change so it don't rerender.

You have to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` method to force the refresh of your component

**Example**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.match.params.topic){
      //Changing the state will trigger the rendering
      //Or call your service who's refreshing your data
      this.setState({
        topic:nextProps.match.params.topic
      })
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

The `componentWillReceiveProps` method is **deprecated**. 
Now the static `getDerivedStateFromProps` is prefered when you're source data are coming from a props params

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

This method shoud return the new state for trigger the remounting, or null for no refresh.

**Example**

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.match.params.topic && props.match.params.topic !== state.topic) {
      //Resetting the state
      //Clear your old data based on the old topic, update the current topic
      return {
        data: null,
        topic: props.match.params.topic
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps method is considered legacy and you should avoid  and use static getDerivedStateFromProps() instead.

Comment: Hm right I didn't see, this will have the same result. I update my answer

Comment: Perfect thanks! Had to correct it to `nextProps.match.params.topic` but worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is only called once while mounting(rendering) the component.
You should use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update your component